# How make React Form Submit return a function?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a problem of Form tag using react state with props drills ,
I have a Submit button that with props `onClick` that accepting a function like this `()=>goto('Somewhere')` so if I click directly open next modal, it doesn't hold for 3 seconds. How to make it hold for 3s then execute `onClick=()=>goto('Somewhere')` I also add parent that has goTo function that manage to open each modal after close

```
//Parent Code
/* Multi-modal steps */
  const goTo = (target) => {
    if (target === 'pay') {
      setModalPay(true)
    } else if (target === 'congrats') {
      setModalPay(false)
      setModalCongrats(true)
    } else if (target === 'done') {
      setModalCongrats(false)
      setModalDone(true)
    }
  }
  
....
return 
(<button type='button' 
   onClick={() => goTo('pay')}
   className='card-btn'>
   Open Modal 
</button>

// Parent has modal children below
<ModalPayment
   slide={true}
   openModal={modalPay}
   paymentMethod={handlePaymentMethod}
   closeModal={() => setModalPay(false)}
   amount={dataCards[1].price}
   next={() => goTo('congrats')}
/>)

// My Modal state which is the children
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)

<form className='payment-form' method='POST' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <button className='payment-btn'
        disabled={!payment}
        onClick={()=>goto('Somewhere')}>
            <img src={ShieldImg} alt='shield' />
               Pay Now
    </button>
</form>
```

My Submit handler are like this

```
const handleSubmit= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)

    // Hold loading for 3s
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (payment === 'tokopedia') {
        payment = 'Tokopedia'
      } else if (payment === 'creditCard') {
        payment = 'Credit Card'
      } else if (payment === 'koinworks') {
        payment = 'Paper Usaha - KoinWorks'
      } else if (payment === 'investree') {
        payment = 'Paper Usaha - Investree'
      }

      paymentMethod(payment)
      setPayment('')
      setLoading(false)
    }, 3000)

    //should return the ()=>goto('Somewhere')
  }
```

Comment: Where is `handleClick` ever invoked and how is it related to that button?  Is the button submitting the form, and you're getting mixed up between the form submit handler and the button click handler?  (Having both seems like a recipe for confusion, why not just perform the actions you want in the submit handler?)  If you're looking to perform some action after a 3-second delay, can you simply use `setTimeout` like you're already showing?  It's not clear to me what you're asking or what this code is attempting to do.

Comment: oh sorry just update the code sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers don't "return a function".  They don't return anything, because nothing is expecting a return value from them.

What you have is a form submit handler **and** a click handler on the form's submit button.  Which is a recipe for confusion.  If the purpose of the button is to submit the form, just let it submit the form and put the logic you want in the form's submit handler.

Remove the click handler from the button:

```
<button className='payment-btn' disabled={!payment}>
  <img src={ShieldImg} alt='shield' />
  Pay Now
</button>
```

And in your `handleSubmit`, perform the logic you want.  If that logic includes performing an operation after 3 seconds, you already have that in a call to `setTimeout`.  Just add your operation to that:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  if (payment === 'tokopedia') {
    payment = 'Tokopedia';
  } else if (payment === 'creditCard') {
    payment = 'Credit Card';
  } else if (payment === 'koinworks') {
    payment = 'Paper Usaha - KoinWorks';
  } else if (payment === 'investree') {
    payment = 'Paper Usaha - Investree';
  }

  paymentMethod(payment);
  setPayment('');
  setLoading(false);
  goto('Somewhere'); // <--- here
}, 3000)
```

Comment: `onClick={()=>goto('Somewhere')}` on the button actually a button that open a modal using `dialog tag` after submitting a form sir. if I remove the `onClick` part it's not going to open the another modal which is the next step

Comment: please check the updated code sir

Comment: @flyingduck92: If `goto('Somewhere')` "opens a modal" then why does that operation *not* "open a modal" when run in the form submit handler?  Whether it's a click handler or a submit handler, that makes no difference.  It sounds like you've made some other mistake or assumption not being asked about here.  Perhaps you could update the question to include a runnable [mcve] (ideally on-site, but anything would help) which *demonstrates* the problem you're trying to describe?

Comment: ah I understand what you mean now I think I found what is the problem here

Comment: It's work sir just like your code above. thank you